# Группировка и агрегация в запросах к SQL в Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Столкнулся с проблемой, наверное синтаксиса, запроса к SQL в Python.
СУБД PostgreSQL

Ошибки с кавычками и пробелами поправил, но все равыно вылезает:

```
AmbiguousFunction                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-ad82da23eca4> in <module>
     29             THEN 'middle'
     30             ELSE 'unknown'
---> 31             END''')
     32 colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
     33 records = cursor.fetchall()

AmbiguousFunction: function avg(unknown) is not unique
LINE 8:         END ages_type, AVG('Pay Rate')
                               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Цель: получить средню зарплату по сотрудникам, разбитым на возрастные группы, обращаясь к SQL  в Python.
Таблица содержит 2 поля:

```
age: [30,34,31,32,30,30,33,33,31,39,63,38,32,46,31,34,31,29,33,33]

PayRate: [28.5,23.0,29.0,21.5,16.56,20.5,55.0,55.0,34.95,34.95,80.0,65.0,43.0,48.5,40.1,34.0,40.0,35.5,41.0,42.75]
```

Необходимо сгруппировать age по возрастам:

- до 33 (junior)
- от 33 до 99 (midle)

и для каждой группы рассчитать средний показатель PayRate

Делаю через case, но python ругается на синтаксис, подскажите пожалуйста где може быть ошибка. Нашел примеры где этот код работает при обращении к БД в терминале, но в Python не пашет

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT
       CASE
            WHEN age <= 33
            THEN 'junior'
            WHEN age > 33
            THEN 'middle'
            ELSE 'unknown'
        END ages_type, AVG('Pay Rate')
FROM hr_dataset
GROUP BY
        CASE
            WHEN age <= 33
            THEN 'junior'
            WHEN age > 33
            THEN 'middle'
            ELSE 'unknown'
            END''')
```

В результате должна получится табличка, с колонками:

- Type
- AVG_pay_rate

Где в Type будут указаны группы возрастов, в а AVG_pay_rate средний показатьль  из pay_rate

Comment: *Таблица содержит 2 поля* Это таблица на SQL-сервере? тогда дайте её в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO скриптов, а не этим невнятным списком.

Comment: *запроса к SQL в Python* Да. Только вопрос НИКАК не связан с python (это будет совсем второй вопрос - как конкретный SQL-запрос выполнить в питоне и получить его результат). Так что питоновскую обвязку текста SQL-запроса можете смело удалять (вместе с тегом), А вот что ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО надо сделать - так это указать конкретную СУБД, которая используется - причём включая её версию. PS. Или всё с точностью до наоборот (если сам SQL-запрос проверенно корректен).

Comment: *python ругается на синтаксис* Точно питон? или он просто транслирует ошибку, которую обнаружил SQL-сервер? как именно выглядит сообщение об ошибке (не исправлять! даже переносы строки и пробелы не удалять и не добавлять)? какой именно оператор продуцирует эту ошибку?

Comment: СУБД PostgreSQL, версию не знаю (

Comment: Ошибка:

  File "<ipython-input-115-7086b91f79b9>", line 16
    WHEN age <= 33\
                    
^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: *СУБД PostgreSQL* Дополните этой информацией список тегов вопроса. Да и в тексте вопроса неплохо бы это указать.

Comment: *Ошибка: File "<ipython-input-115-7086b91f79b9>"* - то есть ошибка - Питоновская, проблема в работе со строками... наверное, дело в том, что неверно квотирован многострочный литерал - его обрамляют тройной кавычкой.

Comment: Да, я думаю что ошибка именно питоновская. Тройные кавычки это ''' request '''?

Comment: Угу, `cursor.execute('''SELECT ... (тело запроса) ... END''')`. И, наверное, слэши в концах строк - они будут лишние...

Comment: снова ругается, но по другому)))
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-10d833e1706b> in <module>
     29             THEN "middle"
     30             ELSE "unknown"
---> 31         END''')
     32 colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
     33 records = cursor.fetchall()

SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "Type"
LINE 8:         END Type,'

Comment: А причем тут SQL ? Для питона это просто текстовая строка. А разобрать он ее не может потому, что у вас после некоторых обратных косых стоят пробелы. Сообщение об ошибке точно говорит в какой строке у вас этот пробел. И надо заметить там еще несколько таких же строк. Используйте текстовый редактор, который показывает пробелы в конце строк (я например в встроенный в mc скопировал ваш тест, он отлично все показал). В принципе если вы тут мышкой выделяете текст то то же отлично эти пробелы видны

Comment: пробелы убрал и в одну строку все записал, но все равно ошибку выдает. Может запятая где то...

Comment: Какую сейчас выдает ошибку ? Я скопировал ваш текст, заменил cursor.execute на print и он отлично текст напечатал

Comment: Хотя сейчас наверное ошибка уже пострегресовская

Comment: Да, действительно, слово Type в postges зарезервированное, если так хотите назвать колонку, заключайте в двойные кавычки. Кстати, обычные строковые константы должны быть в одинарных кавычках, что бы postgres не принял их за имена

Comment: А вообще сначала отлаживайте SQL запросы в средствах разработки БД, например в том же pgadmin. И когда они рабочие переносите в питон. Тогда вы будете лучше понимать кто и на что ругается

Comment: изменилась, да, видимо до этого проблема была в зарезервированной функции. НО теперь новая ))) 
AmbiguousFunction: function avg(unknown) is not unique
LINE 8:         END ages_type, AVG('Pay Rate')
                               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: полная ошибка http://joxi.ru/vAW5apwtqPyMam

Comment: тип данных float64, по идее AVG должно считаться нормально

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том, что аргумент в выражении `AVG('Pay Rate')` неправильный.

Во-первых, кавычки означают, что аргумент - строка. Функция `AVG` для строки не определена.

Тут конечно имелось ввиду среднее значение поля, а поле называется `PayRate` соотвественно должно быть без кавычек правильное имя поля, т.е. все вместе `AVG(PayRate)`.